# How do I add the result of 'for' loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to get and print the sum of all values that fill the `if` condition, but so far no success.

Also, is there a way to delimit `fib()` with a max value, say, 999999, instead of delimiting it through `numMax` operations?

```
fib = function(numMax) {
    for (i = 0, j = 1, k = 0; k < numMax; i = j, j = x, k++) {
        x = i + j;
        if (x % 2 === 0) {
            sum += x;
            console.log(x);
        }
    }
};
fib(32);
```

Comment: You're looking for [the `return` statement.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: I see. Can you please exemplify how do I apply it in this case? I'm only able to print the first number.

Comment: I guess print to what is the question? Currently the console log IS printing those values to the console.

Comment: You completely changed the question. What is it that you're asking? your function doesn't sum up anything now.

Comment: If you are looking to print the sum of all the fibs that fit your condition, then you should keep track of the sum and increment it in your for loop every time the condition is hit by the current value of `x` then either `console.log(sum);` or `return sum;` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can `return` a value, which you can store in a variable:

```
fib = function(numMax){
  var sum = 0;
  for(i=0,j=1,k=0; k<numMax;i=j,j=x,k++ ){
    var x = i + j;
    if (x % 2 === 0){ 
      sum += x; // This is the same like sum = sum + x;
    }
  }
  return sum; // Let's return the calculated sum as the result of the function
};
var result = fib(32); // result contains the value the function returned
console.log(result);
```

I'm not sure about the second part of your question. Do you want, that numMax can not be greater than 999999?

```
fib = function(numMax){
  if (numMax > 999999) {
    numMax = 999999;
  }

  var sum = 0;
  for(i = 0, j = 1, k = 0; k < numMax; i = j, j = x, k++){
    var x = i + j;
    if (x % 2 === 0){ 
      sum += x; // This is the same like sum = sum + x;
    }
  }
  return sum; // Let's return the calculated sum as the result of the function
};
var result = fib(32); // result contains the value the function returned
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a solution that doesn't need me to know beforehand that I need to iterate the loop 32 times, so as not to go beyond 4 million in the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: So you want to stop iterating if `sum`becomes greater than e.g. 4 million? Than you should have a look on [while-loops](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the first part nailed it. As to the second, actually I want `k` to be `< 4000000`, but I don't see how to do it without changing the whole structure of what I have so far.